# How do I make epoll switch between multiple connections?

Tags: c++, sockets, epoll

I am using epoll in what I believe to be the typical manner for TCP sockets (based largely on [this example](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/), but slightly adapted to C++); one main listening socket bound to the port, and each new connection socket (from accept()) is also added for alerts when it's ready for recv(). I have created a test script that basically hammers it with connections and send/receives. When any single client is connected, it will work flawlessly, endlessly.

However, adding a second simultaneous test client will cause one of them to hang and fail. After a couple days of debugging, I finally decided to just have it spit out the socket ID it's working with into a file, and I am perplexed by what I found.

When one script starts, I get just a stream of, in this case, 6. However, when the second script starts, I get a stream of 7. *Just* 7. And it remains at 7, *exclusively* communicating with the second client, completely ignoring the first, until the first one reaches its timeout and closes. (Then, when client 2 reconnects, it gets ID 6 instead.)

It is worth noting that this test script does not use a persistent connection, it disconnects and reconnects after a few messages go back and forth (for a more accurate simulation). But even through that, client 1 is ignored. If I set the timeout high enough that client 2 actually has time to exit, it *still* won't resume with client 1, as whatever it was waiting for just kinda gets lost.

Is this normal behaviour, for epoll (or sockets in general) to completely abandon a previous task when a new one arises? Is there some option I have to specify?

**EDIT:** This is as much of the code as I can show; I'm not necessarily expecting a "this is what you did wrong", more of a "these are some things that will break/fix a similar situation".

```
#define EVENTMODE (EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLHUP)
#define ERRCHECK (EPOLLERR | EPOLLHUP | EPOLLRDHUP)

//Setup event buffer:
struct epoll_event* events = (epoll_event*)calloc(maxEventCount, sizeof(event));

//Setup done, main processing loop:
int iter, eventCount;
while (1) {

    //Wait for events indefinitely:
    eventCount = epoll_wait(pollID, events, maxEventCount, -1);
    if (eventCount < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Poll checking error, continuing...");
        continue;
    }
    for (iter = 0; iter<eventCount; ++iter) {
        int currFD = events[iter].data.fd;
        cout << "Working with " << events[iter].data.fd << endl;
        if (events[iter].events & ERRCHECK) {
            //Error or hangup:
            cout << "Closing " << events[iter].data.fd << endl;
            close(events[iter].data.fd);
            continue;
        } else if (!(events[iter].events & EPOLLIN)) {
            //Data not really ready?
            cout << "Not ready on " << events[iter].data.fd << endl;
            continue;
        } else if (events[iter].data.fd == socketID) {
            //Event on the listening socket, incoming connections:
            cout << "Connecting on " << events[iter].data.fd << endl;

            //Set up accepting socket descriptor:
            int acceptID = accept(socketID, NULL, NULL);
            if (acceptID == -1) {
                //Error:
                if (!(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                    //NOT just letting us know there's nothing new:
                    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't accept on socket: %s", strerror(errno));
                }
                continue;
            }
            //Set non-blocking:
            if (setNonBlocking(acceptID) < 0) {
                //Error:
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't set accepting socket non-blocking: %s", strerror(errno));
                close(acceptID);
                continue;
            }
            cout << "Listening on " << acceptID << endl;
            //Add event listener:
            event.data.fd = acceptID;
            event.events = EVENTMODE;
            if (epoll_ctl(pollID, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, acceptID, &event) < 0) {
                //Error adding event:
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't edit epoll: %s", strerror(errno));
                close(acceptID);
                continue;
            }

        } else {
            //Data on accepting socket waiting to be read:
            cout << "Receive attempt on " << event.data.fd << endl;
            cout << "Supposed to be " << currFD << endl;
            if (receive(event.data.fd) == false) {
                sendOut(event.data.fd, streamFalse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The code has been revised, and the removal of edge-triggering will indeed stop epoll from locking onto one client. It still has issues with clients not receiving data; debugging is under way to see if it's the same issue or something else.

**EDIT:** It seems to be the same error in a different suit. It does *try* to receive on the second socket, but further logging reports that it actually hits an EWOULDBLOCK almost every time. Interestingly enough, the logs are reporting much more activity than is warranted - over 150,000 lines, when I'd expect about 60,000. Deleting all the "Would block" lines reduces it to about the number I'd expect... and lo and behold, the resulting lines create the exact same pattern. Putting edge-triggering *back in* stops the would-block behaviour, apparently preventing it from spinning its wheels as fast as it can for no apparent reason. Still doesn't solve the original problem.

**EDIT:** Just to cover my bases, I figured I'd do more debugging on the sending side, since the hung client is obviously waiting for a message it never gets. However, I can confirm that the server sends a response for every request it processes; the hung client's request just gets lost entirely, and therefore never responded to.

I have also made sure that my receive loop reads until it actually hits EWOULDBLOCK (this is normally unnecessary because the first two bytes of my message header contain the message size), but it didn't change anything.

**'Nother EDIT:** I should probably clarify that this system uses a request/reply format, and the receiving, processing, and sending is all done in one shot. As you may guess, this requires reading the receive buffer until it's empty, the primary requirement for edge-triggered mode. If the received message is incomplete (which should never happen), the server basically returns false to the client, which while technically an error will still allow the client to proceed with another request.

Debugging has confirmed that the client to hang will send out a request, and wait for a response, but that request never triggers anything in epoll - it *completely* ignores the first client after the second is connected.

I also removed the attempt to receive immediately after accepting; in a hundred thousand tries, it wasn't ready once.

**More EDIT:** Fine, fine - if there's one thing that can goad me into an arbitrary task, it's questioning my ability. So, here, the function where everything must be going wrong:

```
bool receive(int socketID)
{
short recLen = 0;
char buff[BUFFERSIZE];
FixedByteStream received;
short fullSize = 0;
short diff = 0;
short iter = 0;
short recSoFar = 0;

//Loop through received buffer:
while ((recLen = read(socketID, buff, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
    cout << "Receiving on " << socketID << endl;
    if (fullSize == 0) {
        //We don't know the size yet, that's the first two bytes:
        fullSize = ntohs(*(uint16_t*)&buff[0]);
        if (fullSize < 4 || recLen < 4) {
            //Something went wrong:
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Received nothing.");
            return false;
        }
        received = FixedByteStream(fullSize);
    }
    diff = fullSize - recSoFar;
    if (diff > recLen) {
        //More than received bytes left, get them all:
        for (iter=0; iter<recLen; ++iter) {
            received[recSoFar++] = buff[iter];
        }
    } else {
        //Less than or equal to received bytes left, get only what we need:
        for (iter=0; iter<diff; ++iter) {
            received[recSoFar++] = buff[iter];
        }
    }
}
if (recLen < 0 && errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
    cout << "Would block on " << socketID << endl;
}
if (recLen < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
    //Had an error:
    cout << "Error on " << socketID << endl;
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Connection receive error: %s", strerror(errno));
    return false;
} else if (recLen == 0) {
    //Nothing received at all?
    cout << "Received nothing on " << socketID << endl;
    return true;
}
if (fullSize == 0) {
    return true;
}

//Store response, since it needs to be passed as a reference:
FixedByteStream response = process(received);
//Send response:
sendOut(socketID, response);
return true;
}
```

As you can see, it can not loop after encountering an error. I may not use C++ much, but I've been coding for long enough to check for such mistakes before seeking assistance.

```
bool sendOut(int socketID, FixedByteStream &output)
{
cout << "Sending on " << socketID << endl;
//Send to socket:
if (write(socketID, (char*)output, output.getLength()) < 0) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Connection send error: %s", strerror(errno));
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

What if it EWOULDBLOCK's? Same as if my motherboard melts - I'll fix it. But it hasn't happened yet, so I'm not going to fix it, I'm just making sure I know if it ever needs fixing.

And no, process() doesn't do *anything* with the sockets, it only accepts and returns a fixed-length char array. Again, this program works perfectly with one client, just not with two or more.

**Last EDIT:** After yet more debugging, I have found the source of the problem. I'll just go ahead and answer myself.

Comment: Post your code. Most likely you didn't add the second connection to the `epoll` set correctly (or at all).

Comment: Just curious, but are you using edge-triggered (EPOLLET) flag?  What is EVENTMODE set to?

Comment: @selbie I am indeed, and I edited the post to include the relevant definitions.

Comment: I can't give you a solution as my epoll's very rusty, but I know it's not supposed to behave like that. At a previous job we used it extensively and never had a problem with multiple connections running simultaneously.

Comment: I would strongly recommend mastering the use of level-triggering before you even think about messing with edge-triggering. And even then, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @David Schwartz While I understand the difference in theory, I'm not sure how the implementation differs, since the tutorials always seem to use edge-triggered. In my own code, just removing EPOLLET causes epoll_wait to return false information, so there must be some other important changes to make.

Comment: Then make a detailed post about the false information you are getting without EPOLLET. It's a much simpler implementation and should be much easier to debug. It sounds like you're just mishandling EWOULDBLOCK. Post your receive function. 99% chance the problem is there. (Loop *until* EWOULDBLOCK, then *stop* looping!)

Comment: @David Schwartz Isn't that the basic principal of edge-triggering? Without that, not even one client would work. _With_ EPOLLET, the problem is that a message from the client never reaches the epoll_wait queue at all; it is totally ignored when a second client is connected. _Without_ EPOLLET, it _still_ does the same thing, with the additional problem of epoll_wait saying a socket has data to be read, but in reality, trying to read on it produces EWOULDBLOCK immediately - as fast as my computer can loop.

Comment: The basic problem with edge-triggering is that you can lose a signal and thus lose a client. With level-triggering, you cannot lose a signal. Read until EWOULDBLOCK, then go back to epoll_wait. (And post your read function. Likely, it keeps looping past EWOULDBLOCK.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.data.fd`? Why are you trying to use that? *`events[iter].data.fd`* is the one with the value you want to receive on. You may want to name your variables more distinctly to avoid this problem in the future so you don't waste everyone's time. This is clearly not an issue with epoll.

Comment: Oh, dammit, you're right! God I'm such an idiot. I fixed that, and it runs beautifully! On the bright side, at least my implementation of edge-triggering was right the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

1) Do not use EPOLLET. It is *way* more complicated.

2) In your `receive` or `read` function, make sure you do not call `read` or `receive` again after getting an EWOULDBLOCK. Go back to waiting for an `epoll` hit.

3) Don't try to peek at the data or measure how much data is there. Just read it as quickly as you can.

4) Remove the socket from the `epoll` set before you close it unless you are positive there is no other reference to the underlying connection endpoint.

It really is that simple. If you do those four things right, you won't have a problem. Most likely, you have botched `2`.

Also, how do you cope with an 'EWOULDBLOCK' when you go to send? What does your `sendOut` function look like? (There are a lot of right ways to do it, but also a lot of wrong ways.)

Comment: 1) epoll was was originally designed for edge-triggered use, and I have no problem whatsoever understanding how it works because it just makes sense. 2, 3, 4, already done, because that also just makes sense. So far, sending has not ever failed or hit EWOULBLOCK - if it ever does, I'll devise some system to handle it, but I'm not about to do so until it happens.

Comment: You are welcome to use it as an edge triggering device, just don't specify the `EPOLLET` flag. It will still trigger on every edge. It just won't die if you miss a signal.

Comment: Remove the socket from `epoll` set before you close it. Why??? I don't see the difference, and always close/shutdown the socket ASAP when it encounted an error.

Comment: @Zind: Shutting down the socket won't remove it from the `epoll` set and closing it will only remove it if you close the last reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: (1) close/shutdown the socket. (2) remove the socket from the `epoll` set. I perform both of the two operations, and I thought you mean that the **sequence** of the two operations matters.

Comment: @Zind: The sequence does matter. Once you `close` the socket, you no longer have a handle to it, which makes it awfully hard to remove it from the `epoll` set.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I understand it now. Thanks so much for answering my confusion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Revising my original answer.

I see a few suspicious things and I have some suggestions.

1. When the listen socket is signaled, the code goes into an infinite loop until accept fails. I wonder if the loop is giving priority to accepting new connections instead of processing epoll events.  That is, you always have a connection ready to be accepted and you never break out of the inner while(1) loop.  Don't loop on accept. Instead, make the listen socket NOT edge triggered when added to the epoll.  Then just accept one connection at a time - such that subsequent epoll events will get processed after accept returns. In other words, take that inner "while(1)" loop out.
2. After your accept call returns a valid socket (and you get done making it non-blocking and added to the epoll with edge triggering), go ahead and call your receive function on the accepted socket. I'm assuming your receive function can handle EWOULDBLOCK and EAGAIN errors.  In other words, for edge-triggered sockets, don't assume you are going to get an EPOLLIN notification for a new socket. Just try to receive on it anyway. If there's no data, you'll get an EPOLLIN notification later when data arrives.
3. Why are you are not listening for EPOLLOUT in regards to your sendOut function? Does sendOut change the socket back to blocking?   In any case, when receive() returns success, change your epoll listener on the socket to EPOLLOUT, then try an opportunistic call to your sendOut function as if you had just gotten an EPOLLOUT notification.
4. And if all else fails, consider turning off edge-triggered (EPOLLET) behavior altogether. Perhaps your recevie function is not consuming all the data from the first EPOLLIN notification.
5. If epoll_ctl fails when adding a new socket, that seems a bit harsh to kill the whole app. I'd just close the offending socket, assert, and continue on.

Comment: I did remove the accept loop, because it seems silly; not even sure why the example has it. (Well I know, why, which is also silly.) Unfortunately, that, combined with removing edge-triggering and immediately calling my receive function, did not affect the results.

Comment: @DigitalMan - I just updated this answer (because I hit "post" too soon originally. Please read again.

Comment: In any case, I'm in the middle of using epoll in my own TCP socket app and I just got it working the other day. I kind of panicked when I saw you post, because I suspected my code had the same bug. However, it seems to handle multiple connections just fine.

Comment: In this case, the communication needs to remain synchronous, so it sends immediately rather than risk something getting in the way or sent out of order. It is set to log send errors, and never has so far. I removed the accept loop, because that's only "better" if it receives two connections in the same _nanosecond_, which I doubt it ever will. However, it has been discovered that the removal of edge-triggering will indeed cause the processing to bounce back and forth as expected. One client still hangs, but now the problem should be more isolated.

Comment: @DigitalMan - If communication needs to remain synchronous, then why try to handle multiple connections simultaneously?

Comment: A response must immediately follow a received message, but there are no rules on the spacing of those request/reply pairs; a connection could easily be open for several seconds (as an extreme example) before data is actually transferred. In the meantime, there may be upwards of 200 other incoming connections.

Comment: @DigitalMan - if you want to be robust with regards to sending, allocate a data structure for each socket connection. Each instance of this data structure would likely include the socket and the output buffer. So you can compute the output and store it into the buffer in case the immediate send fails (and then wait for EPOLLOUT to try again). This likely requires you have a mapping table between sockets to data instances (or make use of epoll.data.ptr).  In regards to your immediate problem, I hope you post your findings back. I'm interested in learning in case I have similar bugs. good luck.